# Why is conductivity isotropic in a plane perpendicular to the z-axis of a tetragonal crystal?

Tags: solid-state-physics

Considering the symmetry of a tetragonal crystal, how can it be proved that conductivity is isotropic in a plane perpendicular to the z-axis?

Comment: Well, is it?  Please post your source of this claim, and for that matter check to see whether the source itself has a reference to a proof.  It would also be helpful to those of us who have forgotten most of their solid-state physics if you posted a model of a tetragonal crystal. :-)

Comment: What would it take for the conductivity to be anisotropic in that particular plane? Is that condition met for a tetragonal crystal?